# Use return data from an angular service resource across all controllers with only one call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a custom Web API written in .NET that returns user's information that will be used in my AngularJS application. I want to be able to call my API once, and then use that returned JSON across my entire AngularJS application without having to recall the API within each of my controllers.

I currently have a factory of services, one of which returns all of the client's details I need to use the in rest of the services.

```
.factory('customApiService', function ($resource) {
    return {
        userInfo: function(userId, callback){
            var api = $resource('../../api/UserInfo/:userId', {
                userId: userId
            }, {
                fetch: 'JSONP',
                'query': { isArray: false }
            });

            api.fetch(function (response) {
                callback(response);
            });
        }
    }
)
```

Now I don't want to call this userInfo service in every controller, but I do want the data to be passed into each without calling my API multiple times.

```
customApiService.userInfo(userId, function (d) {
    var gaProfileId = d.gaProfileId;
    var yelpId = d.yelpId;
    var tripAdvisorId = d.tripAdvisorId;
    var facebookPageName = d.facebookPage;
    var twitterHandle = d.twitterHandle;
    var clientName = d.clientName;
    var searchlightAccountId = d.searchlightAccountId;
    var searchlightDomain = d.searchlightDomainId;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try global variables .

use a $rootScope https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope
$rootScope is available in all controllers an templates .Just inject $rootscope in your controller or wherever required.

Comment: I actually have $rootScope injected for another reason at the moment, but where/when would I call this service to automatically load into the $rootScope before any other controller is initiated? I need to make sure that these variables are set first before continuing to the rest of the app.

Comment: why dont u do it in app run

Comment: Would there be any timing issues if it takes longer than other service calls to complete?

Comment: make your service call from your app.run put whats returned on to the rootscope and access it across your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read of your description and responses to other questions, it sounds like you're trying to make an asynchronous call before the rest of your app starts up. This is possible, but complex, and sort of voids the point of Angular in the first place. As I see it, you have two options:

1. **QUICK HACK**: If you really want this kind of behavior, why start your app at all? Do your request first, before you define your app in the first place, then define your app in the result handler for the request.
2. **RIGHT WAY**: Alter the behavior of your services and controllers to tolerate not having enough information to fully start. A lot of times this is less difficult than it sounds. Usually you can just chain a promise into their initialization block of code to wait for the data you need. Take a look at Brian Ford's "Angular Modal" project, at the lines of code I've highlighted here:

   https://github.com/btford/angular-modal/blob/master/modal.js#L25-L36

   This technique sets up a promise to return from the function. If the data it needs is already loaded from the service, it resolves the promise immediately. Otherwise, it makes the call to get what it's after, and you can see later (line 39) that the module uses promise.then() to wait until it has the data it needs to run.

   This is a great pattern for both controllers and services when working with asynchronous data.

If using a $resource call instead, note that most $resource calls return a promise in a property called $promise. You can do something like this:

```
var MyController = function($scope) {
    // This will get set soon!
    $scope.myData = null;


    var myResource = $resource('/path/to/:someId', { someId: '@id' });
    myResource.get({ someId: 1 }).$promise.then(function(data) {
           $scope.myData = data;
    });
};
```

You can do more things in the .then() resolution callback for the promise, like initialize more parts of your controller, etc. There are also ways you can delay starting your entire controller until the resource is available. One really cool way is if you happen to be using the Angular ui-router module, there is a "resolve" option when defining each route. You can use that to call the $resource as shown above, and ui-router will wait to start your controller/view until it has what it needs.

Comment: I'd like to do the second option, but is there any way to make a promise through a $resource call instead of $http. I can't seem to find any information.